lateinit property requestPermission has not been initialized with Health connect Expo React native
I'm trying to implement a walking steps counter with react-native-health-connect my problem is that wen i;m trying to grant permission after initializing the app crash and give this error lateinit property requestPermission has not been initialized is there any way to solve this problem.
Please help me with it
`
this is the code I'm using from https://www.notjust.dev/projects/step-counter/android-health-connect
import { initialize, requestPermission, readRecords} from 'react-native-health-connect';
import { Permission } from 'react-native-health-connect/lib/typescript/types';
import { TimeRangeFilter } from 'react-native-health-connect/lib/typescript/types/base.types';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

const useHealthData = () => {
const [steps, setSteps] = useState(0);
const [flights, setFlights] = useState(0);
const [distance, setDistance] = useState(0);
const [androidPermissions, setAndroidPermissions] = useState<Permission[]>([]);

const init = async () => {
// initialize the client
const isInitialized = await initialize();

if (!isInitialized) {
console.log('Failed to initialize Health Connect');
return;
}

// request permissions
const grantedPermissions = await requestPermission([
{ accessType: 'read', recordType: 'Steps' },
]);

setAndroidPermissions(grantedPermissions);
};

useEffect(() => {
if (Platform.OS !== 'android') {
return;
}

init();
}, []);`

return {steps, flights, distance}
}

`

Seems like there is an issue with expo native modules on version 2.0.2 of react-native-health-connect. I was able to get it working the old fashioned way though (I'm also using expo SDK 50)

Hi Can you give more detail how were you able to fix it? im facing the same issue and following the same guide. thank you
